# Python "cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not open" , report if there is a connection problem

Tags: python

I am an Oracle DBA who has a lot of oracle databases to maintain, I am creating a script to check the connection of all the databases, Hence using the below-mentioned script to check the database connection one by one with a loop, The script works perfectly if all the databases connection are working, but when any database is down or non responsive,
i get message as :

```
    cursor.close()
    cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: not open
```

the loop breaks and I don't get status of remaining databases. I want to view the output as :-

```
    +---------------+------------------------------+
    | INSTANCE_NAME | STATUS                       |
    +===============+==============================+
    | ORA_DB1       | Database is working properly |
    +---------------+------------------------------+
    | ORA_DB2       | The database is down         |
    +---------------+------------------------------+
```

My code is as follows:-

```
    import cx_Oracle
    import termtables as tt

    DB_CONN = [['ORA_DB1','system/********@hostname1:6673/ORA_DB1'],
              ['ORA_DB2','system/********@hostname2:6673/ORA_DB2']]


    list=[]
    counter=0

    for x in range(len(DB_CONN)):
       try: 
          con = cx_Oracle.connect(DB_CONN[x][1])
  
          # Now execute the sqlquery 
          cursor = con.cursor()
          cursor.execute("select instance_name from v$instance")
          dataset1 = cursor.fetchall()
          results = ','.join([str(item) for row in dataset1 for item in row])
          success_list= [results, "Database is working properly"]
          list.append(success_list)
          counter=counter + 0


        except (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError,cx_Oracle.InterfaceError) as e:
              error, = e.args
              if error.code == 1034:
                 print('Database connection error')
                 error_list= [DB_CONN[x][0],"The database is down"]
                 list.append(error_list)
                 counter=counter + 1
                 cursor.close()
                 continue
              else:
                 print("There is a problem with Oracle", e)
                 continue


     string = tt.to_string(
         list,
         header=["INSTANCE_NAME", "STATUS"],
         style=tt.styles.ascii_thin_double,
         # alignment="ll",
         # padding=(0, 1),
         )
     print(counter)
     print(string)
```

Answer (score 0):

If a connection can't be opened, you won't be able to open (and hence close) a cursor.

Even in the successful-connection case, you probably should remove the explicit close. Instead, let the end-of-scope do the cleanup.

Don't forget to check other errors such as ORA-1017 - which one day you'll hit.  I would probably reverse the logic and only assume success if the query returns a record.

You will want to add some connection timeout options to your connection configuration, either with an Easy Connect Plus syntax like `dbhost.example.com/orclpdb1?connect_timeout=30` or by using a sqlnet.ora file.  See the cx_Oracle documentation such as https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/ha.html

Also consider trying to connect in parallel.